# type org.json.jsonobject cannot be converted to jsonarray

Tags: android, json, listview

I have problem with my app and my logcat shows tt type org.json.jsonobject cannot be converted to jsonarray. I'm not sure how to solve this problem. What does it mean? How to change my code

Here's the logcat info:

```
10-15 06:33:05.394: E/JSON Parser(1322): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value {"table2":[{"status":"queueing","phonenumber":"123","remarks":"w","peoplenumber":"5"},{"status":"","phonenumber":"345","remarks":"ss","peoplenumber":"3"},{"status":"","phonenumber":"555","remarks":"f","peoplenumber":"2"},{"status":"","phonenumber":"1345","remarks":"","peoplenumber":"5"}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
10-15 06:33:05.394: W/dalvikvm(1322): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d80b20)
10-15 06:33:05.394: E/AndroidRuntime(1322): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-15 06:33:05.394: E/AndroidRuntime(1322): Process: com.zanqi.datatolistview, PID: 1322
10-15 06:33:05.394: E/AndroidRuntime(1322): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-15 06:33:05.394: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
10-15 06:33:05.394: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
10-15 06:33:05.394: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
10-15 06:33:05.394: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
10-15 06:33:05.394: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
10-15 06:33:05.394: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-15 06:33:05.394: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-15 06:33:05.394: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
10-15 06:33:05.394: E/AndroidRuntime(1322): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-15 06:33:05.394: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at com.zanqi.datatolistview.MainActivity$ProgressTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:85)
10-15 06:33:05.394: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at com.zanqi.datatolistview.MainActivity$ProgressTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
10-15 06:33:05.394: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
10-15 06:33:05.394: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-15 06:33:05.394: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     ... 4 more
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.zanqi.datatolistview.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{5282e178 V.E..... R....... 0,0-1664,192} that was originally added here  
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:348)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at com.zanqi.datatolistview.MainActivity$ProgressTask.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:66)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at com.zanqi.datatolistview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-15 06:33:06.322: E/WindowManager(1322):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private Context context; 
    private static String url = "http://172.22.112.190:8080/Qproject/servlet/Qaction?action_flag=find"; 
    private static final String phonenumber = "Number"; 
    private static final String peoplenumber = "Info"; 
    private static final String remarks = "Remarks"; 
    private static final String status = "status"; 

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 

    ListView lv; 

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        new ProgressTask(MainActivity.this).execute(); 
    } 


    private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> { 

        private ProgressDialog dialog; 

        private ListActivity activity; 

        private Context context; 

        // private List<Message> messages; 

        public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) { 
            this.activity = activity; 
            context = activity; 
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context); 
        } 

        protected void onPreExecute() { 
            this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start"); 
            this.dialog.show(); 
        } 

        @Override 
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) { 
            if (dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing()){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist,
                    R.layout.list_item, 
                    new String[] {phonenumber, peoplenumber, remarks, status}, 
                    new int[] {R.id.vehicleType, R.id.vehicleColor, R.id.fuel,
                               R.id.status });
            setListAdapter(adapter); 
            //select single ListView item 
            lv = getListView();
        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) { 
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // get JSON data from URL 
            JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) { 
                try { 
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i); 
                    String number = c.getString(phonenumber); 
                    String info = c.getString(peoplenumber); 
                    String remarkss = c.getString(remarks); 
                    String statuss = c.getString(status); 

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
                    // Add child node to HashMap key & value 
                    map.put(phonenumber, number); 
                    map.put(peoplenumber, info); 
                    map.put(remarks, remarkss); 
                    map.put(status, statuss); 
                    jsonlist.add(map); 
                } catch (JSONException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
            } 
            return null; 
        }
    }
}



public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream iStream = null; 
    static JSONArray jarray = null; 
    static JSONObject Jasonobject = null;
    static String json = ""; 

    public JSONParser() { } 

    public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) { 
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url); 
        try { 
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet); 
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine(); 
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode(); 
            if (statusCode == 200) { 
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
                InputStream content = entity.getContent(); 
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content)); 
                String line; 
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
                    builder.append(line); 
                } 
            } else { 
                Log.e("==>", "Failed to download file"); 
            } 
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

        // Parse String to JSON object 
        try { 
            jarray = new JSONArray( builder.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) { 
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString()); 
        }

        // return JSON Object 
        return jarray; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Please check your URL in your browser.

Comment: What do you mean? There's nothing wrong with my url... I did receive the data but the app stops and logcat shows that JsonObject cannot convert to JArray

Comment: Can you show format of JSON.?

Comment: Post your logs where you are getting this error.

Comment: post log cat as well as response string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code, may be it works for you

```
JSONObject table = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    JSONArray json = table.getJSONArray("table2");
    for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
              try { 
                        JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i); 
                        String number = c.getString(phonenumber); 
                        String info = c.getString(peoplenumber); 
                        String remarkss = c.getString(remarks); 
                        String statuss = c.getString(status); 

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
                        // Add child node to HashMap key & value 
                        map.put(phonenumber, number); 
                        map.put(peoplenumber, info); 
                        map.put(remarks, remarkss); 
                        map.put(status, statuss); 
                        jsonlist.add(map); 
                    } catch (JSONException e) { 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                    }
    }
```

i think you have jasonArray in jsonObject

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there are two different types of JSON: arrays and objects. An array has `[]` round it at the outer level, and an object has `{}` round it.

In the Java world, `Object` is the superclass of every class. If the JSON library were sensible, then `JSONObject` would be a superclass of `JSONArray`, and you'd be able to use `JSONObject` for everything. Unfortunately, though, it's not; and you have to know whether what you're parsing is an array or an object in order to decide whether to put it into a `JSONArray` or a `JSONObject`.

The error you're getting is because you're reading in this JSON:

```
{"table"...   }
```

and trying to interpret it as a `JSONArray` when it's really a `JSONObject`. If you're always going to be getting the same sort of data back from the server, you can just change the type of what you're parsing to `JSONObject`. If it'll sometimes be one and sometimes the other, you need some shenanigans to check what it is before parsing it, or a `try`/`catch` block to try one first then the other.

But usually, you're receiving a specific format of data and you know which you're going to get.

Answer (score 0):

Try This code it will help you, It's working for me.

```
 InputStream mIs = null;
            String result = "";
            JSONArray jArrayEvent = null;
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                mIs = entity.getContent();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          try{
                BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mIs,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if(line.trim().equals("\n"))
                        continue;
                    stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                }
                mIs.close();
                result=stringBuilder.toString();
            }catch(Exception e){

                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            }
            try {
                jArrayEvent = new JSONArray(result);
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ity seem you have problem with your json
and from server you are getting jsonObject like {
....
.....
...
}
and in this line you try to convert in Array which is exception you are getting

```
JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

Just check your json and convert it to appropriat JSONObjects and JSONArrays.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON that you parse from the URL is not in a JSONArray format, but in a JSONObject format.

```
{"table2":[ ... ]}
```

The leading curly brackets tell you it's an object. `"table2"` is the first attribute of this object, and it's value is an array - probably the one that you want.

You can get your array by this (in your JSONParser in your last `try` clause):

```
Jasonobject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
jarray = Jasonobject.getJSONArray("table2");
```

That should give you your array.

Btw, it's a coding standard in Java to name variables in camel case, starting with a lower case letter. So for writing pretty code you can rename your JSONObject variable like this:

```
static JSONObject jasonObject = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String str = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
 JSONObject Jsonobject = new JSONObjectstr );
 jarray = Jsonobject .getJSONArray("table2");
```